# Displaying 2 separate home pages based on authentication status

Tags: react.js, next.js

I want to have 2 separate pages at the root URL for logged-in users and logged-out users. (at "`/`").

After advice on this sub, this is what I've come up with, using parallel routes. But is that OK, or can be done better:

`/layout.tsx`:

```
import './globals.css'  
import type { Metadata } from 'next'  
import { Inter } from 'next/font/google'  
const inter = Inter({ subsets: \['latin'\] })  

export const metadata: Metadata = {  
 title: 'Create Next App',  
 description: 'Generated by create next app',  
}  
export default function RootLayout({ authenticated,  unauthenticated}: {
   authenticated: React.ReactNode  
   unauthenticated: React.ReactNode  
}) {  
    const isLoggedIn = isLoggedIn(); // true/false
   
    return (  
       <html lang="en">  
          <body className={inter.className}>
            {isLoggedIn ? authenticated : unauthenticated}
          </body>  
       </html>  
  )  
}
```

`/@authenticated/page.tsx`:

```
export default function Dashboard() {
    return (
        <main>
            <h1>Authenticated</h1>
        </main>
    )
}
```

`/@unauthenticated/page.tsx`:

```
export default function Homepage() {
    return (
        <main>
            <h1>Unauthenticated</h1>
        </main>
    )
}
```